# Function .JSON_OBJECT does not exist

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I have 2 tables and I try to get statuses from table `status` and add to each status info about an author from a `user` table. I created the same database on my laptop and everything works fine. But I've got an error when published the database on Heroku using ClearDB:

```
[42000][1305] FUNCTION heroku_1ecaeb2cbfaf113.JSON_OBJECT does not exist
```

Without `JSON_OBJECT` query works fine. What's going on? Where I made a mistake?

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    login VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(15),
    avatar VARCHAR(150),
    ts INT,
    hash BINARY(60)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS status (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    note VARCHAR(300),
    author VARCHAR(15),
  ts INT,
  replyTo INT UNSIGNED
);
```

My query:

```
SELECT
  status.id,
  status.note,
  status.ts,
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'login', statusAuthor.login,
    'name', statusAuthor.name
  )
FROM
  user,
  user statusAuthor
  INNER JOIN status ON statusAuthor.login = status.author
WHERE
  user.login = 'some_user' AND status.replyTo IS NULL
ORDER BY status.id
DESC
LIMIT 11;
```

Comment: The JSON datatype and JSON functions were added in MySQL 5.7. What version are you running?

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much, it was 5.5